# Silevis Reactgrid: Can i get Data list from range selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

from example -> https://reactgrid.com/examples/?example=liquidity-planner

[I need to get data from selected to do something (ex. calculate summary)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NqAK.png)

How to get Data list ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.